# How to verify fstab concisely?

Tags: mount, fstab, verification

I have been using the following command so far to verify my `/etc/fstab`:

```
sudo findmnt --verify
```

Unfortunately, it spills out warnings for each unreachable disk (which I don't care about) and I have not found a flag to change that. Any clever tip to get rid of these warnings or an alternative standard tool?

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is `mount -a`; is that something you've considered?

Comment: If you don't care about unreachable disks, why are you adding them to `fstab`? There are various ways to handle removable disks without adding them to `fstab`; many of them would be features or extensions of your desktop environment of choice. If you are modifying your `fstab` so often that you need an automated syntax checker for it, for example `vim` will highlight incorrect `fstab` entries with red background if you just activate its syntax highlighting features.

Comment: I want something that does not change anything (a sort of dry-run) and is independent of the editor used.
I prefer to work text-based, so binding it to the desktop environment is also not appropriate. I like to configure mounting locations of a few regularly-used external disks statically, though.

Comment: Ah, I can use `mount -af`, but I am having another weird error there: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/712127/mount-unexpectedly-calling-espanso

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sudo findmnt -T /mnt/foo` or `sudo findmnt -S UUID=insertuuidhere` to limit devices you want to verify, though you can only specify one device at a time (run the command for each device)

or you can specify a separate fstab file and use `sudo findmnt -F /path/to/alt/fstab --verify` and remove entries you don't need in the latter.